# Elastic Beanstalk environment can't decide whether it's Ready or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I run `eb create <NEW_ENV_NAME>` to create a new environment, it starts up, with an error (details below), and reaches `Ready` status:

```
> eb status
Environment details for: [REDACTED]
  Application name: [REDACTED]
  Region: us-east-1
  Deployed Version: [REDACTED]
  Environment ID: [REDACTED]
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Python 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.5.1
  Tier: WebServer-Standard
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2017-09-07 21:39:49.750000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Grey
```

...However, when I try to make a change to the environment using the AWS web console, I get the error:

`Unable to validate settings: Environment named distro-worker2 is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.`

Confusing!

FYI, the error on environment creation is:

`Creating load balancer failed Reason: Default subnet in us-east-1a not found`

...so, it fails to start up a load balancer. What I'm trying to do is switch it from `Load balancing/auto scaling` to `Single instance` in Settings, but AWS thinks it can't do this because the environment isn't `Ready`. But... it *is* `Ready`!

...right?

It looks like I can launch directly to a single instance, w/o load balancer, using

`eb create --single <ENVIRONMENT_NAME>`

...but that still doesn't help me understand whether `Ready` means `Ready` or not.

Comment: did you check the issue with "Default subnet in us-east-1a not found". In AWS, your account should have a default subnet (like a vpn for your services) in every region. If indeed it is missing, then you should recreate it.

Comment: I made various changes to the VPC and configuration files and got it working, but never figured out whether the environment instance was actually Ready or not!